# Idiomatic short lifespan local objects akin to RAII

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, raii

I came across this fragment of Objective-C:

```
NSNumber *theBalance = 
    [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]
     numberFromString: [textField text]];
```

This seems to leak the `NSNumberFormatter`. In C++ I would do one of two things:

1. use `auto` (i.e. stack) storage for the `NSNumberFormatter`
2. use RAII (e.g. `shared_ptr`)  to manage the life of the `NSNumberFormatter`

In Objective-C neither of these options seem to be possible. I tried on the stack:

```
NSNumberFormatter fmt;
```

But this doesn't compile. As far as I can find there's no direct equivalent of RAII in Objective-C. I'm probably looking at the problem from the wrong angle as a mainly C++ programmer, so:

1. In the general case what's the correct, idiomatic (modern) Objective-C way of handling the life of objects like the `NSNumberFormatter` here? Do I really have to do it explicitly myself?
2. In the specific case is there a better way of solving the actual problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the classes like *NSString*, *NSArray*, and so on, have the convenience constructors like, `[NSString string]` and `[NSArray array]` which return the autoreleased objects. *NSNumberFormatter* doesn't have any convenience constructors. So, you can send a `autorelease` message to let it autoreleased when the autorelease pool drains.

```
NSNumber *theBalance = [[[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]
                       numberFromString: [textField text]];
```

If you want to retain(own) the reference of the object, you can omit the `autorelease` and release it later when you are done with it. You do it like this,

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *theBalance = [numberFormatter numberFromString: [textField text]];

// Later... somewhere in your code...
[numberFormatter release];
```

I know the above is not a detailed explanation. I'd suggest you to [read this post](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-memory-management.html) by which, I hope, you would get some clear idea about memory management!

Comment: `autorelease` appears to be the information I was missing, which combined with thinking like a C++ programmer sent me off on a bit of a tangent. `autorelease` just says "at some point in the future call release" where "some point" is guaranteed to be after the end of the current statement (sequence point?) right?

Comment: @awoodland: Yes, it's exactly like that. In Cocoa we often speak of ownership, and we say that with `release` and `autorelease` we give up ownership of an object: immediately with `release`, sometime later with `autorelease`. Typically, autoreleased object are freed at each runloop iteration. You might be interested in reading [Let's build NSAutoreleasePool](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-02-lets-build-nsautoreleasepool.html) by Mike Ash to gain understanding what's really happening.

Comment: @awoodland, Here "some point" doesn't mean the end of current statement. It means that the object will be released whenever the current autorelease pool is destroyed. Its guaranteed that the object will not be released before the execution of the current method (where you have created/autoreleased the object) is over. You will get problem only when you try to access the object outside the method where you have created/autoreleased the object.