# strange error compiling main module using g++

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile the below code using "g++ main.cpp -c" but it gives me this strange error .. any ideas?

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘Graph*’ to ‘int’
main.cpp:9:17: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Graph::Graph(int)’
main.cpp:10:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

This is my main module which i am trying to compile and below that is the graph class i have  in graph.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Graph g;
  g = new Graph();
  char* path = "graph.csv";
  g.createGraph(path);
  return 0;
}
```

AND this is my Graph class

```
    /*
 * graph.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 28, 2012
 *      Author: ajinkya
 */

#ifndef _GRAPH_HPP_
#define _GRAPH_HPP_

#include "street.hpp"
#include "isection.hpp"
#include <vector>

class Graph
{
 public:
  Graph(const int vertexCount = 0);
  //void addIsection(Isection is);
  //void removeIsection(int iSectionId);
  Isection* findIsection(int);
  void addStreet(int iSection1, int iSection2, int weight);
  void createGraph(const char *path); //uses adj matrix stored in a flat file
  //void removeStreet(int streetID);
  void printGraph();
  ~Graph();
 private:
  //Isection *parkingLot;
  //Isection *freeWay;
  int** adjMatrix;
  std::vector <Street*> edgeList;
  std::vector <Isection*> nodeList;
  int vertexCount;
};

    #endif
```

Comment: Consider using `std::string`s for strings, `boost::ptr_vector`s for vectors of pointers, a matrix class for matrices, and not using `using namespace std;` (especially when it serves absolutely no purpose).

Answer (score 5):

This is C++, not Java or C#. `new` doesn't work the same way here.

`new` expressions return pointers. You cannot assign a pointer to a `Graph` (i.e. a `Graph*`) to a variable of type `Graph`:

```
Graph g;
g = new Graph(); // Graph = Graph* ? nope
```

Seems like the compiler is trying to be "helpful" and trying to use your constructor take takes an `int` argument to make a value of type `Graph`, but it can't convert a `Graph*` to an `int`.

When you write `Graph g;` you *already have a `Graph` object*. You don't need to create one with `new`. In fact, you probably don't even *want* to do that, as it will lead [to memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-is-it-a-memory-leak-what-could-i-catch-if-i-shall-use-such-things-in-c/8840302#8840302).

Then there's this line:

```
char* path = "graph.csv";
```

`"graph.csv"` has type `char const[10]` so you should not assign it to a `char*`. In the past you could, but that turned out to be a bad idea. That feature was marked as deprecated, and now it was completely removed in C++. Instead of doing that you can:

- Make an array out of it: `char path[] = "graph.csv";`;
- Make a pointer to it with the proper type: `char const* path = "graph.csv";` (this works because [array types decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c));

Comment: Except that, unlike Java, you don't write `Graph g;`, you write `Graph* g;` which is causing his **error**.

Comment: "*`"graph.csv"` has type `char const[10]` so you cannot assign it to a `char*`*" Morally you shouldn't, but technically you certainly can. @Tim : In idiomatic C++ you certainly _do/should_ write `Graph g;`.

Comment: @Tim - there's no need to make it a pointer and use `new` here at all - this isn't Java after all.

Comment: I don't understand.  "The new keyword allocates memory for an object or array of objects of type-name from the free store and returns a suitably typed, nonzero pointer to the object."  I thought typical usage was `MyClass* instance = new MyClass;`

Comment: Also, from OP's error: `main.cpp:9:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘Graph*’ to ‘int’`  It is clearly showing that his constructor is returning a `Graph*` and he's trying to assign it to a `Graph`.  This is throwing the error, correct?

Comment: @Tim that's typical if you want to do all the memory management yourself, but an `auto` storage object will do just nicely here and not have any worry about leaks/exceptions. You can just write `Graph g;` and be done with it, which avoids a whole world of pain for free.

Comment: I did not know that was a thing.  Do you have a link to further reading for how it works for me?

Comment: I guess working on Objective-C all day is destroying my brain.

Comment: @Tim - I have exactly the opposite problem in Ojective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753680/idiomatic-short-lifespan-local-objects-akin-to-raii

Comment: I tried this
` Graph g;
  char const* path = "graph.csv";
  g.createGraph(path);'

I am getting these errors now :

 /tmp/ccmSJigi.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Graph::Graph(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `Graph::createGraph(char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `Graph::~Graph()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `Graph::~Graph()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Ajinkya : That means you're not linking graph.o and main.o. How are you building your code?

Comment: yeah my bad .. I did a g++ graph.cpp main.cpp now and even though graph.cpp compiled earlier without errors i get an error on g++ graph.cpp main.cpp saying -

In function `Graph::addStreet(int, int, int)':
graph.cpp:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `Isection::pushOutIsectionList(Isection*)'
graph.cpp:(.text+0x41a): undefined reference to `Isection::pushInIsectionList(Isection*)'
graph.cpp:(.text+0x473): undefined reference to `Isection::pushOutStreetList(Street*)'
graph.cpp:(.text+0x485): undefined reference to `Isection::pushInStreetList(Street*)'

Can i share the files here somehow ?

Comment: @Ajinkya Are you forgetting the `-c` flag?

Comment: i am doing a g++ graph.cpp -c and then a g++ graph.cpp main.cpp

Comment: @Ajinkya: ah, I see. After you compiled all the parts (including main.cpp) with `-c` you should see a bunch of files ending in `.o` in your directory. The final step should be with *all* of those `.o` files. Like `g++ graph.o isection.o main.o etc.o`.

Comment: got you! thanks for the help!! i am new to c++ and wanted to use g++ for compiling rather than any gui based compiler. This makes the learning more fun and clearer.

Answer (score 2):

That should probably be `g = Graph();` and forget the `g = new Graph;`. The reason is that `new` returns a *pointer* to the created object (e.g. a `Graph*`), not an object value.

Better still, just do `Graph g;` and forget about assigning anything to `g`. This will automatically create a `Graph` for you by calling `Graph`'s no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Graph* g;`

It has to be a pointer.

Comment: For a bit more explanation: the only viable constructor for `Graph` is the one taking an `int`. This could be a conversion constructor as it isn't `explicit` but this conversion can't be used as the argument type mismatch. You might want to make your constructor `explicit` to improve error messages for situations like the one quite and to avoid accidentally creating a `Graph`.

Comment: His constructor has a default value of 0: `Graph(const int vertexCount = 0);` therefore `Graph()` = `Graph(0)`

Comment: It can still be be `explicit`, however. My point was just to explain where the odd error message about an `int` to `Graph` conversion came from.

Comment: Insisting on making everything a pointer and using `new` to initalise (or assign values to) them is a very Java-esque way of thinking, which doesn't map directly onto C++ as well.

Comment: If you advocate for it be a pointer, please at least add something about it being a smart pointer (or that it must be explicitly deleted and that throwing exceptions will probably cause memory leaks/drive the author insane).

Answer (score 0):

First of all `new Graph()` returns a `Graph*`.  In c++, a constructor with one argument can be implicitly called, so currently your code is really meaning:

```
g = Graph(new Graph());
```

What you want is

```
g = Graph();
```

Comment: This will needlessly assign to `g` the exact same value it already has. How is that an answer?

Comment: When I learned C++ I was taught to always initialize my variables myself and never leave it to the system or the compiler.  I also was fixing his problem as it was and explaining what is current code was actually doing.

Comment: All I can say is that if that's true, you were taught very poorly. This defines [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).